# UK IP address lookup API

Tags: php, api, ip-geolocation

im looking for a UK IP address lookup api ( or PHP script ) to find the location of a user. I want to produce more relevent results for a user when searching a directory. All the ones I have found just say 'UK' and dont get any more information than that. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Regards,

Phil

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of companies that sell/provide IP information very detailed.

One of them is [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location)

Answer (score 0):

[MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/) is one of a number of geolocation providers that provide interfaces to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

[From my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468199/get-country-location-of-an-ip-with-native-php/2468273#2468273):

MaxMind provide a [free country and city lookup module](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php), which can either be installed as an Apache module, or there is code for a purely PHP solution available too.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.ipgp.net They have a free API with accurate results