# how to log IP by country in PHP?

Tags: php

how to determine which country the IP is coming from ? like e.g
when a visitor came to a site, I can log the ip using

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ,
```

but that's all a combination of numbers,
if let's say I want to log only the IP address coming from the US,AU,UK, or any other country that I want specifically,
how to do that "without" using any database tables where the logger is hosted ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468199/get-country-location-of-an-ip-with-native-php

Comment: Try to google for `ip country`, you'll come up with results like this http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country

Comment: You "have" to use some kind of database to lookup the IP address against list of countries.

Comment: You have to use a lookup API like [`ipinfodb.com`](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php). There is no mathematical order to the geo-location of IP addresses, the only solution is to use a lookup table, be that one you host your self or somebody else's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice web service for this is http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/.

You can get the data as XML or JSON and use the country attribute of the header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IP to country mappings provided by [Webnet77](http://software77.net/geo-ip/). The database contains about 100000 entries for various IPv4 blocks and can be downloaded in CSV format. You can later include that CSV in your logger script to find a country.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a geoip location service like [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com)